# LINQ Lambda, need to query to a very confuse database, how should I do it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

I have these two tables from the DB Model: (MVC5 App)

[image]

The column Period from the Absence Table should be a foreign key and refer the primary key of TimePeriod, however it is not the case, unfortunately, and I can't change it to foreign key (the tables are already filled with data), so the column Period is basically and int. (Is the fact that I'm turning a column already with data on a foreign key what doesn't allow me to?).

Anyhow, I'm trying to do a LINQ query to get the Absences from an Employee in a certain year. However to get that year, I need to make a JOIN with the TimePeriod, plus I would like to get the TimePeriod data along with the absence, which makes it harder without the damn foreign key.

What should I do? Should I create a model that contains the Absence and TimePeriod all together? I just don't know... Thanks for the help. Any questions, I'm all ears.

These are the Library classes that represent the tables:

```
[Serializable] 
public class Absence
{
    public Int32 IDAbsence;
    public Int32 IDEmployee;
    public Int32 Period;
    public DateTime BeginDate;
    public DateTime? EndDate;
    public AbsenceType AbsenceType;
    public AbsenceStatus AbsenceStatus;
    public List<Justification> Justifications;
    public List<Notification> Notifications;

    public Absence() { }

    public Absence(Int32 IDAbsence, Int32 IDEmployee, Int32 Period, DateTime BeginDate, DateTime? EndDate, AbsenceType AbsenceType, AbsenceStatus AbsenceStatus, List<Justification> Justifications, List<Notification> Notifications)
    {
        this.IDAbsence = IDAbsence;
        this.IDEmployee = IDEmployee;
        this.Period = Period;
        this.BeginDate = BeginDate;
        this.EndDate = EndDate;
        this.AbsenceType = AbsenceType;
        this.AbsenceStatus = AbsenceStatus;
        this.Justifications = Justifications;
        this.Notifications = Notifications;
    }



    }

[Serializable] 
    public class TimePeriod
    {
        public Int32 IDTimePeriod;
        public DateTime? StartTime;
        public DateTime? EndTime;

        public TimePeriod() { }

        public TimePeriod(Int32 IDTimePeriod, DateTime? StartTime, DateTime? EndTime)
        {
            this.IDTimePeriod = IDTimePeriod;
            this.StartTime = StartTime;
            this.EndTime = EndTime;
        }
    }
```

Then I have other classes where I do the ObjectMapping of these objects...

Comment: can you put that in some sort of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joins to not require that the model or database have foreign keys in place. So assuming a simple mapping in your model:

```
var absences = from p in db.TimePeriods
               join a in db,Absences on p.IDTimePeriod = a.Periond
               where p.StartTime.Year = theYear
               where a.Employee.ID = theEmployeeId
               select a;
```

(if the mapping can't handle the field of the date, you can just check for a range that includes the one year.)